# How to check a particular value in all Maps in an RDD[Map[Int,String]] at a strech using scala?

Tags: scala, collections, mapreduce

I want to check particular value in all Maps in an  RDD[Map[Int,String]] at a strech using scala. My csv file is,

```
Map(0 -> sunny, 1 -> hot, 2 -> high, 3 -> false, 4 -> no)
Map(0 -> sunny, 1 -> hot, 2 -> high, 3 -> true, 4 -> no)
Map(0 -> overcast, 1 -> hot, 2 -> high, 3 -> false, 4 -> yes)
Map(0 -> rainy, 1 -> mild, 2 -> high, 3 -> false, 4 -> yes)
Map(0 -> rainy, 1 -> cool, 2 -> normal, 3 -> false, 4 -> yes)
```

Here I want to check all the last value in each map, ie **no,no,yes,yes,yes** with a particular value **check**(yes/no) at a single stretch.

Comment: What means `last value`? Value with biggest key?

Comment: @SergeyLagutin, here last value means each map contains Map(0->bb, 1->mnj,....). THis 0,1,..etc represents the column number of actual data. We need to take the last column value. So from each map, last value, here, 4 -> no, 4 -> no, 4 -> yes,....., So take no, no,yes...from this pair and check witha string value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scala> val a = List(Map(0 -> "sunny", 1 -> "hot", 2 -> "high", 3 -> "false", 4 -> "no"),
     |   Map(0 -> "sunny", 1 -> "hot", 2 -> "high", 3 -> "true", 4 -> "no"),
     |   Map(0 -> "overcast", 1 -> "hot", 2 -> "high", 3 -> "false", 4 -> "yes"),
     |   Map(0 -> "rainy", 1 -> "mild", 2 -> "high", 3 -> "false", 4 -> "yes"),
     |   Map(0 -> "rainy", 1 -> "cool", 2 -> "normal", 3 -> "false", 4 -> "yes"))
a: List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String]] = List(Map(0 -> sunny, 1 -> hot, 2 -> high, 3 -> false, 4 -> no), Map(0 -> sunny, 1 -> hot, 2 -> high, 3 -> true, 4 -> no), Map(0 -> overcast, 1 -> hot, 2 -> high, 3 -> false, 4 -> yes), Map(0 -> rainy, 1 -> mild, 2 -> high, 3 -> false, 4 -> yes), Map(0 -> rainy, 1 -> cool, 2 -> normal, 3 -> false, 4 -> yes))

scala> sc.parallelize(a)
res0: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String]] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:15

scala> val l = sc.parallelize(a)
l: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String]] = ParallelCollectionRDD[1] at parallelize at <console>:14

scala> def check( s : String) : Boolean = if (s.equals("yes")) true else false
check: (s: String)Boolean

scala> val res = l.map{ x => check(x(4)) }
res: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Boolean] = MappedRDD[4] at map at <console>:18


14/11/28 00:18:47 INFO DAGScheduler: Stage 5 (take at <console>:21) finished in 0.020 s
14/11/28 00:18:47 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 5.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
14/11/28 00:18:47 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 5 finished: take at <console>:21, took 0.026501 s
false
false
true
true
true
```

**UPDATE**
The following will be `true` only when all values are `true` else it will be `false`.

```
scala> res.reduce( _ && _ )
```

Comment: Not List[Map[Int,String]], It is RDD[Map[Int,String]]...., and I need to check all values is yes or no. NOt take one by one. If my check string is yes, check all that values are yes, If yes do function1 else function2

Comment: It is an RDD[Map[Int,String]] only. See `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String]]` I've updated the result to take care of your final requirement.